# Sorting List<MyObject>

Tags: java, generics, list, sorting

Which is the quickest way in Java to sort a list

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList
```

based on some numerical property of MyObject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call

```
Collections.sort(myObjectList, comparator);
```

where `comparator` is a reference to an instance of `Comparator<MyObject>` which compares any two instances of `MyObject` appropriately.

Alternatively, if this is a "natural" sort order for `MyObject`, you could make `MyObject` implement `Comparable<MyObject>` and just call

```
Collections.sort(myObjectList);
```